# Linear regression on training data in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

```
training <- data.frame('target'=c(33,44,55,43,22,33), 'age'=c(12,23,12,13,44,33), 'weight'=c(111,222,123,124,125,112))
```

Here is a simplified example of my training data that i am trying to conduct a linear regression on. The real data has 1 target column and 29 other columns. How would i go about conducting this linear regression with the multiple columns?

Answer (score 2):

just use this code (the dot stands for all columns other then the target column informed before the tilde "~":

```
lm(target ~ ., training)
```

Though when using that many variables you should think about variable selection to increase performance of the model (stability, precision, etc.). One topic to look into concerning this would be "step wise variable selection": http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/37-model-selection-essentials-in-r/154-stepwise-regression-essentials-in-r/